# performance metric of a software library in WinCE

Tags: windows-ce, metric

Is there a way to calculate how many mips consumed by a module (libraray) running on wince? We are developing an audio library and want to give playback in wince (Renesas SH-4A core). How to calculate the number of mips (millions of instructions per second) consumed by this library? If not, **what is the equivalent metric for measuring the performance of a library on wince.** - Thank you, VT.

Answer (score 1):

Closest you would come is using a high resolution timer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692(VS.80).aspx

Also check out this msdn article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404355.aspx